# Gallery Slider Images Too Big

Tags: python, html, css, django

This is my first post on stackoverflow. So I am sorry for some untypical stuff in this post.

I have programmed a Django Website with a gallery slider, but I have no idea why the images are way too big. Look Here: https://imgur.com/a/YNxu7

I have spent a lot of hours to fix it but, but without sucess.

```html
{% block content %}

<!--

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
-->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
            <!-- Pictures -->
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="/static/img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cover1">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Picture 1</h3>
                    <p>Some details to it</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="/static/img/portfolio/2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cover2">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h3>Picture 2</h3>
                    <p>Also some details</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pictures are naturally pretty big, so while they are getting resized, they aren't resizing enough. I've tried adjusting the size of the picture itself and it causes the slider to adjust its size too. Thus instead of the picture being constrained to the slider, the slider is constraining itself to the picture. You didn't post your css, but you might want to try defining a size to the slider and then making your image constrained to that size (keeping its proportions, of course) by setting its max-width and/or height to 100% and the other to auto. If you find it still looks too big (due to it maintaining the aspect ratio), you could either manually resize the image or try setting it as a background image instead, in which case you can use `background-size: contain`.

Comment: Thank you I will try it!! (And give Feedback if this solve the problem) :D